# Is it possible to get classes on the WordNet dataset?

Tags: nlp, dataset, nltk, wordnet

I am playing with WordNet and try to solve a NLP task.

I was wondering if there exists any way to get a list of words belonging to some large sets, such as "animals" (i.e. dog, cat, cow etc.), "countries", "electronics" etc.

I believe that it should be possible to somehow get this list by exploiting hypernyms.

Bonus question: do you know any other way to classify words in very large classes, besides "noun", "adjective" and "verb"? For example, classes like, "prepositions", "conjunctions" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from polm23, I found this solution, which exploits similarity between words, and prevents wrong results when the class name is ambiguous.
The idea is that WordNet can be used to compare a list `words`, with the string `animal`, and compute a similarity score. From the nltk.org webpage:

`Wu-Palmer Similarity: Return a score denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the depth of the two senses in the taxonomy and that of their Least Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor node).`

```
def keep_similar(words, similarity_thr):
    similar_words=[]
    w2 = wn.synset('animal.n.01')

    [similar_words.append(word) for word in words if wn.synset(word + '.n.01').wup_similarity(w2) > similarity_thr ]
    return similar_words
```

For example, if `word_list = ['dog', 'car', 'train', 'dinosaur', 'London', 'cheese', 'radon']`, the corresponding scores are:

```
0.875
0.4444444444444444
0.5
0.7
0.3333333333333333
0.3076923076923077
0.3076923076923077
```

This can easily be used to generate a list of animals, by setting a proper value of `similarity_thr`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just check if the category is a hypernym of the given word.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def has_hypernym(word, category):
    # Assume the category always uses the most popular sense
    cat_syn = wn.synsets(category)[0]

    # For the input, check all senses
    for syn in wn.synsets(word):
        for match in syn.lowest_common_hypernyms(cat_syn):
            if match == cat_syn:
                return True
    return False

has_hypernym('dog', 'animal') # => True
has_hypernym('bucket', 'animal') # => False
```

If the broader word (the "category" here) is the lowest common hypernym, that means it's a direct hypernym of the query word, so the query word is in the category.

Regarding your bonus question, I have no idea what you mean. Maybe you should look at NER or open a new question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. This is very close to what I wanted to do, but does not return a list of animals. However, I believe it could be used to somehow create a list of animals, but I did not manage to figure it out. It helped me a bit in finding my own solution, which exploits similarity, instead. I have upvoted it, it is a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I need to better explain myself. Your solution actually works perfectly for the class `animal`, and a list of animals can be obtained just by simply looping over `has_hypernym()`. However, some classes can be way more ambiguous than `animal`, thus a binary classification can be inaccurate in these cases (I did some tests with other types of classes).